# Unable to load mysql JDBC driver for Quartz in OSGI bundle hosted in felix

Tags: osgi, quartz-scheduler, apache-felix

I am trying to use Quartz Job store functionality. I have specified the propery for DB in quartz.properties, but its unable to find the class and throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource 
I have already installed my sql driver, common pool and common dbcp and all from the ebr repository of Spring --which provides OSGi complaint bundle.
Really really stuck on this, this question is in plenty but without any specific answer.
Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: I would guess that quartz is trying to lookup a class without access to the proper classloader.  This is a common problem in many libraries once run in an OSGi env.

Comment: i do have that much of pointer and id tried some work around as ynamic import .. but does not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

The way I got Quartz working was to create by own wrapper bundle containing quartz-all-2.1.1.jar and c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar. From there I export all the quartz packages and import the DataSource packages (Oracle in my case).

The only other thing I had to do was create a fragment bundle to contain the implementation of the org.quartz.Job interface so that Quartz could find it when it deserialised it from the DB.